# Passing image path via angularJs controller to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to pass the image path to HTML page via angularJS controller in ASP.NET MVC project. The image stored in "contents/images" folder in the project. I am getting 404 (Not Found) Error. I am using IIS express.
Below is the code

### HTML

```
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >
        <div data-ng-repeat="img in mainCtrl.images">
            <div class="item">
                <img src={{img.path}} alt={{img.name}} class="banner">
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

### Angular Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
    .module('TestApp')
    .controller('mainCtrl', mainCtrl);

    mainCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

    function mainCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.images = 
            [
                { path: '..\Contents\images\banner\banner1.jpg', name:'banner1', item:"item active" },
                { path: '..\Contents\images\banner\banner2.jpg', name:'banner2', item:"item"},
                { path: '..\Contents\images\banner\banner3.jpg', name:'banner3', item:"item"}
            ]

    }

})();
```

It is trying to look for the images at http://testApp/Contents/images/banner/banner1.jpg

What is the correct way of passing the path of the image which is still going to work even after I published to IIS Server

-Alan-

Comment: if you are using alias mainCtrl why you set the value on $scope, you should write:   this.images = .....

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you pass the base url as the path? Or maybe try replacing

```
<img src={{img.path}} alt={{img.name}} class="banner">
```

with

```
<img ng-src="{{img.path}}" alt="{{img.name}}" class="banner">
```

quick edit: sorry, I hadn't formatted the html a second ago.